# Как добавить параметры к тегу link в Битрикс?

Tags: битрикс

При подключении стилей в Битрикс используется конструкция

```
$APPLICATION->SetAdditionalCSS("styles.css");
```

Нужно добавить

```
rel="preload"
```

чтоб получилось

```
<link rel="preload" href="styles.css">
```

В доках Битрикса решения не нашел (https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/reference/cmain/setadditionalcss.php)

Как подобное реализуется?

Comment: Есть `AddHeadString`, но как понимаете - он добавляет в `<head>`. Если вы грузите все css в конце body - он не подойдет

Comment: @u_mulder если в админке включить опцию переносить подключения в конец, то перенесет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для подключения своей строки используйте метод D7 [`\Bitrix\Main\Page\Asset::addString`](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_d7/bitrix/main/page/asset/addstring.php)

```
use \Bitrix\Main\Page\Asset;

Asset::getInstance()->addString('<link href="'.$APPLICATION->GetCurDir().'"style.css";  type="text/css" rel="preload" />');
```

Тоже самое можно выполнить и не на D7, а по страинке, как предложил @u_mulder

```
<?$APPLICATION->AddHeadString('<link href="'.$APPLICATION->GetCurDir().'"style.css";  type="text/css" rel="preload" />',true)?>
```

Если нужно чтобы стили подгружались в конце страницы, то в настройках "Главного модуля" в административном разделе активируйте соответствующую опцию.

Answer (score 0):

Надо добавить rel="preload". Подключено вот так:

```
$assets->addCss(SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH . '/dist/styles.css');
```